# Is there a database/listing of the TRUE PHYSICAL screen sizes of android devices?

Tags: android, aspect-ratio, screen-size

After long researching the web/SO I could not find how to determine the **true physical** size of android devices screen size.

The Android API does give you a method to inquire the screen size, which should have been simple:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
display.getMetrics( dm );
mDpiRatio = dm.ydpi / dm.xdpi;
```

**Yet,** the values returned by the manufacturers are simply **far from true...** which is a problem when you want to display a decent UI or images with proper aspect ratio.

So, is there an alternative way to query these values / any open source database of these dimensions?

Comment: `the values returned by the manufacturers are simply far from true` ... What are you saying?! Anyway, here's a page you might find interesting: http://www.emirweb.com/ScreenDeviceStatistics.php

Comment: `Yet, the values returned by the manufacturers are simply far from true...` sometimes it is for sure. `which is a problem when you want to display a decent UI` no, it's not. millions of developers do it everyday. Maybe you just have to study more how it's done.

Comment: Dudes .. That's an unfortunate truth with many devices (Samsung S4, and even google's own Nexus 5) and have been discussed all over SO... What I was asking is not if it's true, but for a solution

Comment: You shouldn't be asking how to get physical size of device because it won't help. There are millions of devices and I guess you won't like the idea to keep separate image for each of them. You could look into **[9-patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)** or other creative ways of dealing with the problem. Sometimes simplest solution is not the best option out there.